# Show FULL WEEK-DAY NAME and FULL MONTH NAME in the Mac menu bar?

Tags: mac, date

How can I show the FULL WEEK-DAY NAME and FULL MONTH NAME in the Mac menu bar? What should I change to make it possible?

Comment: "Why" questions don't work well on Stack Exchange, as the only people who could answer are, in this instance, Apple. Your definition of perfection may differ from theirs too.

Comment: You are right. I've changed the question text.

Comment: Microsoft Windows has options to choose between full and abbreviated weekday and month names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using only macOS, you can't.  The only Preferences allow these options:
[image]
There is an Advanced setting within the Language and Region settings that ideally should allow you to customize the date formats:
[image]
However, I've tried to change the "Medium" setting (which is what seems to be showing in my menubar), and it doesn't have an effect.

There are many other tools which will let you customize a new Date/Time item in the menubar (hiding the OS one), including iStat Menus and BusyCal (both are not free).  You could probably find some free ones too.

Comment: +1, yeah, the clock has always been separate to the general date/time formatting; an island unto itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I know that MacOS cannot do that. I will search for a free date-time menu-bar display.